# What is Duration in MonitorLM output?

Tags: licensing, monitoring

What is duration specified in `MonitorLM` output?
Is it start hour and minutes or is it total number of hours and minutes used?

Answer (score 3):

Duration, represented by the tag `%PROC_DURATION` in a [`monitorlm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/monitorlm.html) template file, is the elapsed time during which the client has been running.

See also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MonitoringMathLM.html